# Combining 2 different graph outputs in R into one graph

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

So I used the following code, to generate graphs, where appl and apple generate 2 different graphs and now I want to combine them into a single graph

```
data <- ddply(data, .(Value), summarise, 
               N    = length(means),
               mean = mean(means),
               sd   = sd(means),
               se   = sd(means) / sqrt(length(means)) )

apple=ggplot(data, aes(x=Value, y=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=.1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()

dat <- ddply(dat1, .(Value), summarise, 
               N    = length(means),
               mean = mean(means),
               sd   = sd(means),
               se   = sd(means) / sqrt(length(means)))

appl=ggplot(dat, aes(x=Value, y=mean)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=.1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `combining into one plot`?

Comment: I want the two scatter plots to be in the same graph

Answer (score 1):

The answer involves combining the datasets into one big one, with an additional column specifying to which dataset that subset belonged. There is no need for creating plots separately and combining them. Let's assume that column is named `id`, then you can use an additional argument in `aes` to get the plot to work, i.e. `aes(x=Value, y=mean, color=id)`. Combining the datasets can be done using `rbind`.

A code example:

```
df1 = data.frame(Value = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                 means = runif(1000))
df2 = data.frame(Value = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                 means = runif(1000) + 0.5)
df1 = ddply(df1, .(Value), summarise, 
               N    = length(means),
               mean = mean(means),
               sd   = sd(means),
               se   = sd(means) / sqrt(length(means)))
df1$id = "ID1"
df2 = ddply(df2, .(Value), summarise, 
               N    = length(means),
               mean = mean(means),
               sd   = sd(means),
               se   = sd(means) / sqrt(length(means)))
df2$id = "ID2"
df_all = rbind(df1, df2)
ggplot(df_all, aes(x=Value, y=mean, color = id)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=.1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se),alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Which results in the following graph:

[image]

Note that I have had to invent some data due to lack of example data form your side, so this might not entirely fit your situation. However, it nicely illustrates the approach.

Comment: The two graphs have different standard errors...how would I incorporate that?

Comment: After combining the datasets, and setting the `aes` correctly, everything will go automatically correct. Just try it and see. If you make your example reproducible, i.e. provide me with the data, I could provide you with a working example.

Comment: even easier, `ggplot2` has an optional `data` argument for each layer, so you could add a new layer with the second dataset.

Comment: You would have to add a layer for each geom, i.e. 4 geoms in this case. My solution is neater I think, requires less code, and is more in line with the philosophy of ggplot2.